# VS Code em pt-BR

Tags: visual-studio-code

O VS Code ainda não tem suporte a tradução para português, alguém sabe de há alguma forma de fazer isso? alguma extensão ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Procure no marketplace de plugins do site oficial ou no projeto do vs code no github

Comment: Jovem foi lançado o Pack em PT-BR para o Vs Code, olha o edit que fiz na minha primeira resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: 12/03/2018**

Foi lançado o "Portuguese (Brazil) Language Pack for VS Code" vc pode ver a documentação nesse link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-pt-BR

E conforme dito na resposta antiga basta fazer o `"locale": "pt-br"` Documentação sobre os **Locales** https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

Nota oficial sobre essa atualização dos ***Language Packs*** para a **Versão 1.21** do VS Code. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_language-packs

---

Ainda não existe uma versão estável de pt-BR para o VS Code. Porém existe uma versão para quem participa do "Insiders build". Mas aparentemente os desenvolvedores da Microsoft não vão lançar novas linguagens até definirem melhor como vai ser o "language packs"

> "After discussion we decided not to bring it to the official release until we define a story for "language packs". However, it will stay in the Insiders."

**[Loc] Request to add Brazilian Portuguese language in VS Code #25107** https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25107
*(Link do comunicado oficial no GitHub do projeto)*

Link das linguagens suportadas atualmente, mas veja que eles falam isso: *

> By default, VS Code picks up the operating system's display language,
>   falling back to English (US) if the locale is not supported.

Resumindo, vc pode colocar um "**pt-BR**" no seu `"locale":"pt-br"` que assim que tiver o pack da linguagem o seu VS Code vai ir para português, e enquanto não houver a tradução vai continuar em **EN** como *fallback*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link do site oficial da linguás suportadas https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales

E ainda se te interessar existem algumas opções de plugins do tipo  *Spell Checker* - **Corretor Ortográfico**

Link dos plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=portugues&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance